# Minifabric problem with apiserver and fabric 2.2.1 error join on the channel in multihost configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

I had created a custom network with my organizations and my peers running 100% on a host with which I was interfacing via an ApiServer based on this: https://kctheservant.medium.com/rework-an-implementation-of-api-server-for-hyperledger-fabric-network-fabric-v2-2-a747884ce3dc The problem is when I switched to using networking on 2 hosts using docker swarm. When I join the channel from the second host I get the error: "unable to contact the endpoint". So I switched to using "minifabri" which promises easy use, and in fact the network is customized in a short time, even there it gave me an error when joining the channel of the second host, solved by setting the variable EXPOSE_ENDPOINT = true. The problem is that now nmon I can no longer get my apiserver to work, what I did is (as indicated in the Readme) replace the contents of the "main.js" file with my server code and run the "apprun" command. This gives me an error if I leave the server listening on a port, while it is successful if I comment out the last 2 lines of the code. The problem is that I don't have how to query the server if I don't have a listening port. Summarizing my questions are:

how can I create an api server done like that on minifabric?
alternatively how can I solve the problem on the Fabric base (I can't find an EXPOSE_ENDPOINT variable to set), probably the problem will be the same as the one I had on minifabric. Thanks to those who will help me.